node js aws-ses Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
I'm using node.js on macOS, with express module to generate a static page that has a Submit form which I want to run an send() function on the Server.
The problem in question:
It seems my send() function fails to be recognized from the HTML. The following error is generated:
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
I suspect this is the result of my node project not being set up correctly.

The index.html
<head>
  <title>Hotel</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  ...

  <script src="sendemail.js"></script>
</head>
...
<form>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <input class="form-control" id="recipient-name" type="text" placeholder="Nom" data-sb-validations="required" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="recipient-address" placeholder="E-mail" data-sb-validations="required, email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" placeholder="Votre message" data-sb-validations="required"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn1" onclick="send()">Envoyer</button>
                </form>

The sendemail.js
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk"); // This line is the problem
// Set the region
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

function send() {
    console.log("Emo log send");
    const recipient_name = document.getElementById('recipient-name').value;
    const recipient_email = document.getElementById('recipient-address').value;
    const message = document.getElementById('message-text').value;

    console.log("Name:", recipient_name);

    console.log("Address:", recipient_email);

    console.log("Message:", message);
    // Create sendEmail params
    let params = {
        Destination: {
            /* required */
            CcAddresses: [
                "emoleumassi.dev@gmail.com",
                /* more items */
            ],
            ToAddresses: [
                "germanndolo@gmail.com",
                /* more items */
            ],
        },
        Message: {
            /* required */
            Body: {
                /* required */
                Html: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: "HTML_FORMAT_BODY Emo Leumassi asds",
                },
                Text: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: "TEXT_FORMAT_BODY Emo Leumassi asd",
                },
            },
            Subject: {
                Charset: "UTF-8",
                Data: "Test email Emo sdsd",
            },
        },
        Source: "contact@emoleumassi.com" /* required */,
        ReplyToAddresses: [
            "contact@emoleumassi.com",
            /* more items */
        ],
    };

    // Create the promise and SES service object
    let sendPromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
        .sendEmail(params)
        .promise();

    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
    sendPromise
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data.MessageId);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err, err.stack);
        });
}

The index.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Villa app listening on port ${port}!`);
});

My file structure:

Notes:
calling send() from onclick doesn't work.

require not defined in brouser.

You are trying to load the aws-sdk in your front-end code using a back-end approach. You can use the aws-sdk in the browser but from the looks of your code this needs to be handled on the server. Set up an express route handler, have your front-end send a form to that endpoint and handle the form inputs. Then you can then issue your AWS.SES messages on the sever.
